# Error installing psycopg2 using pip in virtualenv on Suse 15 SP5

Tags: python-3.x, pip, psycopg2

I have pre-production environment where is running in Sles 15-SP5, where i have some python scripts.

Each python scripts has their own virtualenvironment. In one of the virtualenvironments I need to install psycopg2 using pip, but i have the below error:

```
**(venv) /home/Script1> pip3 install psycopg2**
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.9.tar.gz (384 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Ã python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  â exit code: 1
  â°â> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ldhms7jg/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ldhms7jg/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ldhms7jg/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ldhms7jg/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ldhms7jg/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Ã Encountered error while generating package metadata.
â°â> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I installed all these postgres packages, but i can't solve the problem.

**/home> zypper se -si postgresql**
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

```
S  | Name                 | Type    | Version            | Arch   | Repository
---+----------------------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------
i  | postgresql           | package | 16-150500.10.3.2   | noarch | SLE-Module-Basesystem15-SP5-Updates
i  | postgresql-contrib   | package | 16-150500.10.3.2   | noarch | SLE-Module-Server-Applications15-SP5-Updates
i  | postgresql-devel     | package | 16-150500.10.3.2   | noarch | SLE-Module-Server-Applications15-SP5-Updates
i  | postgresql-server    | package | 16-150500.10.3.2   | noarch | SLE-Module-Server-Applications15-SP5-Updates
i+ | postgresql15         | package | 15.5-150200.5.19.1 | x86_64 | SLE-Module-Basesystem15-SP5-Updates
i+ | postgresql15-contrib | package | 15.5-150200.5.19.1 | x86_64 | SLE-Module-Server-Applications15-SP5-Updates
i+ | postgresql15-devel   | package | 15.5-150200.5.19.1 | x86_64 | SLE-Module-Server-Applications15-SP5-Updates
i+ | postgresql15-server  | package | 15.5-150200.5.19.1 | x86_64 | SLE-Module-Server-Applications15-SP5-Updates

    Note: For an extended search including not yet activated remote resources please use 'zypper
    search-packages'.
```

I install psycopg2-binary package and works well, but later i need to go to a production-environtment, and i can read using the binary package is not recommended.

I tried to find the file called "pg-config" in the machine, but i don't find anything.

I find that the postgres binary are in this path: **/usr/lib/postgresql15/bin**

```
/usr/lib/postgresql15/bin # ls -al
total 12416
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     654 Feb 22 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      16 Nov 10 10:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   77224 Nov 10 10:16 clusterdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   85576 Nov 10 10:16 createdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   77576 Nov 10 10:16 createuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   73024 Nov 10 10:16 dropdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   72968 Nov 10 10:16 dropuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  151904 Nov 10 10:16 initdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   48240 Nov 10 10:16 oid2name
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  106760 Nov 10 10:16 pg_amcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   43600 Nov 10 10:16 pg_archivecleanup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  152328 Nov 10 10:16 pg_basebackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   64568 Nov 10 10:16 pg_checksums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   60144 Nov 10 10:16 pg_controldata
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   72936 Nov 10 10:16 pg_ctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  398880 Nov 10 10:16 pg_dump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  115248 Nov 10 10:16 pg_dumpall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   72904 Nov 10 10:16 pg_isready
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   98248 Nov 10 10:16 pg_receivewal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   98320 Nov 10 10:16 pg_recvlogical
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   68776 Nov 10 10:16 pg_resetwal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  185192 Nov 10 10:16 pg_restore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  143040 Nov 10 10:16 pg_rewind
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   47904 Nov 10 10:16 pg_test_fsync
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   39544 Nov 10 10:16 pg_test_timing
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  163600 Nov 10 10:16 pg_upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  101512 Nov 10 10:16 pg_verifybackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  109960 Nov 10 10:16 pg_waldump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  197344 Nov 10 10:16 pgbench
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8704184 Nov 10 10:16 postgres
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Nov 10 10:14 postmaster -> postgres
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  803808 Nov 10 10:16 psql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   85672 Nov 10 10:16 reindexdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   90056 Nov 10 10:16 vacuumdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   48112 Nov 10 10:16 vacuumlo
```

Please how I can solve this?

thanks

Comment: In my OpenSuse install, `pg_config` is provided by the `postgresql-server-devel` package.

Comment: Hi, @snakecharmerb, I installed package postgres-server-devel as you told me, but continue without works.